# How fast are Count and Capacity?

Tags: c#

I often write code like this:

```
if ( list.Count > 0 ) { }
```

Is this efficient? Does this operation look like:

- Iterate through the list and count its elements
- Result: 986,000 elements
- Is 986,000 greater than 0?
- return true

Or like this:

- Retrieve the stored number of elements in the list (986,000)
- Is 986,000 greater than 0?
- return true

That is, to get the number of elements in the list, do you have to count all the way through the list, or is the number of elements recorded somewhere? And is this the case for all `ICollection` classes?

What about the `Capacity` of the list?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I often write code like this:  `if ( list.Count > 0 ) { }` Is this efficient?

Yes. That retrieves the count in the list, which is stored in a field inside the list, and compares it to zero.

Now a question you did not ask:

> What about  `if ( sequence.Count() > 0 ) { }` ?  (Notice the parentheses on `Count()`.)

We interrogate the sequence at runtime to see if it is a list that has a `Count` property that can be computed efficiently. If it does, we call it. If not, we count the entire sequence one item at a time, and then compare that to zero.

> Isn't that incredibly inefficient?

Yes.

> What would be more efficient?

`if (sequence.Any())`

> Why is that more efficient?

Because it attempts to iterate over *one* element. If it succeeds, then `Any` is true; if it fails then `Any` is false. You don't need to count the number of jellybeans in the jar in order to know if there are more than zero. You only need to look to see if there is at least one.

In addition to being considerably more efficient, the code now reads like the intended meaning of the code. If you are intending to ask "are there any items in the list?" then ask "are there any items in the list?" and not "is the number of items in the list greater than zero?"

> What about the `Capacity` property of a list?

That tells you how much space has been pre-allocated in the list's internal data structures. It is the amount of items the list can store before it has to allocate more memory.

Comment: "We interrogate the sequence at runtime to see if it is a list that has a Count property that can be computed efficiently." What do you mean by that? Do you check for a property called `Count`, or do you check if `ICollection<T>` is implemented? The second one has funny special cases if you use the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Looking via Reflection for a property named Count would be both slow and unreliable. We look for an implementation of the interface. And yes, you can get false negatives as a result of covariance issues. If it hurts when you do that then don't do that.

Comment: @CodeInChaos if the check for `ICollection<T>` fails, the code then checks for non-generic `ICollection`.  So most of the framework collections are safe from the covariance problem.

Answer (score 6):

The `Count` property in `List<T>` - and all other `ICollection<T>` implementations in the BCL - is an O(1) operation, that means it is fast and independent of the number of the number of elements in the list.

There also exists an extension method `Count()` that can be called on any `IEnumerable<T>`. This method is O(n), which means its runtime depends on the number of elements in the enumerable. However, there is one exception: If the enumerable really is an implementation of `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` it uses the `Count` property making it again an O(1) operation.

---

The `Capacity` property is normally nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: Well, considering that op talks about 986,000 elements in the list a clever management of the Capacity in the right place *can* bring significant benefits.

Comment: The capacity is doubled every time it is hit, so managing the capacity only brings a real benefit if you are filling a lot of lists.

Comment: That't what I mean: it *can* bring benefits in some situations (example CAD programs)

Comment: I think it's a correct. Last time I read about it was many years ago, *don't think* that something was changed about that.

Comment: @Tigran: Yes, I also think it is true - The samples in the MSDN also support it. I just had a brain-fart and already deleted that comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code instead: `list.Any()`. It may be slower than `List<>.Count`, but will work for any IEnumerable<> in most efficient way.

`Capacity` can be greated than `Count`. It is used when you plan to add a lot of items later.

Imlementation of List.Count is the following (it is really O(1) ):

```
public int Count
{
  get
  {
    return this._size; // this is a field
  }
}
```

Comment: While `.Any()` is preferable to `.Count() > 0`, it is slightly less efficient because it creates an enumerator on the collection.

Comment: fot List or any collection that stores c

Answer (score 2):

Count is `O(1)` operation on List.

It's fastest way possible.

**Count** :   This is a number of elements present in the list actually.

**Capcity** : Explains better documentation:

> Gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure
>   can hold without resizing .

Answer (score 1):

Capacity does not tell you how many objects are in your list - just how much the list is ready for.

From MSDN:

```
Capacity is the number of elements that the List<T> can store before resizing is required, while Count is the number of elements that are actually in the List<T>.
```

List.Count is super fast and is an accessed property whereas List.Count() is from IEnumerable and I believe has to do a complete enumeration through the list.